# Are there any Python NLP tools to figure out how many ways a sentence can be parsed?

Tags: python, nlp

I want to be able to measure ambiguity of a sentence, and my current my idea to do so is by measuring how many ways a sentence can be parsed. For example, the sentence "Fruit flies like a banana" can have to interpretations.

So far I have tried using the Stanford Parser, but it only interpreted each sentence in one way. My other idea was to measure how many different parts of speech each word in a sentence could mean, but each POS tagger I found only marked each word with 1 tag even when it could be multiple.

Are there are tools to do either?

Comment: Questions asking for tool recommendations are [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow (they tend to be opiniated, quickly outdated, and attract spam posts). As a new member, you probably should take the [tour] (it's short!) and spend some time to read the [help].

Answer (score 0):

From the Stanford Parser [FAQ page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml), hope it helps:

> **Can I obtain multiple parse trees for a single input sentence?**
>
> Yes, for the PCFG parser (only). With a PCFG parser, you can give the option `-printPCFGkBest n` and it will print the `n` highest-scoring parses for a sentence. They can be printed either as phrase structure trees or as typed dependencies in the usual way via the `-outputFormat` option, and each receives a score (log probability). The `k` best parses are extracted efficiently using the algorithm of Huang and Chiang (2005).